# Unidentifiable error in parallel_for

Tags: c++, exception, concurrency, parallel.for

I'm trying to learn how to use a parallel_for loop for simple tasks.  I am trying to use the following code:

```
Concurrency::parallel_for(int(0), 50, [&](int i)
{
    try
    {
        printf("%d,", i);
    }
    catch (exception e)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
});
```

Now, if I put it in main, it works fine, and prints out what I expect appropriately.  However, if I put it in a .lib I am linking against, it compiles, but I receive the following error:

"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA8541A020 (ntdll.dll) in main.exe: RangeChecks instrumentation code detected an out of range array access."

So my questions:

1) Why would this work in the main method directly, but not in my .lib?  I feel like it wouldn't compile if I was missing headers- how can I fix this?

2) No amount of Googling has led me to a solution on what exactly this error means and how I can resolve it.  More confusing is the fact that all fifty valid numbers print before failure.  Has anyone come across this issue?

Thanks for the insight- I'll keep looking myself!

Comment: Why are you using a capturing lambda when you are not using anything worth capturing? And why wrap `printf()` in a `try/catch` that just calls `printf()` again? `printf()` doesn't raise an exception to begin with.  `Concurrency::parallel_for(0, 50, [](int i) { printf("%d,", i); });`

Comment: I'm fairly certain the problem isn't in the code you've posted.  Not using a capturing lambda is a good idea, but shouldn't be the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird- it works in Debug mode, so there must be some compiler flag I'm missing in Release or something.